# Execute Python script in QlikView 11

Tags: python, qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to execute an external python script in QlikView Desktop 11. I've tried everything but the EXECUTE command does not seem to work. The script fetches a file and writes into it.

Comment: Did you Also tick the Script (Allow Database Write and Execute Statement) check box in User Preferences -> Security should be checked Python script?

Comment: I am using QlikView, not QlikSense.

Comment: You need to include the full path to python.exe.eg:

EXECUTE C:\Python27\python.exe c:\Users\User123\Desktop\test.py;

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: replace \ with \\

Comment: Checked the preferences too! Nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable external execution.
goto script editor -> settings -> check "can execute external programs"

[image]

Comment: Already enabled! I've enabled override security from user preferences and document properties as well.

Comment: then the problem is not in QV